# Is this a way to instantiate a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

Starting to learn javascript but am confused as to how to define a class. 
Is the following a way to define a class?

```
var bar = function (a, b) {
    var product = a*b;
    var sum = a+b;

    return function() {return product / sum};
};
```

I think that it is just a function but was told that it was also a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a plain function

```
function (a, b) {
    var product = a*b;
    var sum = a+b;

    return product / sum;
};
```

This would be more like a class in java because you're assigning a function to an object:

```
var bar = function (a, b) {
    var product = a*b;
    var sum = a+b;

    return function() {return product / sum};
};
```